# How to plot pcolormesh for specific coordinate points instead of a meshgrid from 1D lat lon values

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I have a dataframe which contains three columns: **Latitude**, **Longitude** and **Variable**. There are roughly 100K rows in it. I need to plot a colormesh of this data which is showing weird lines and areas.

I have seen posts everywhere to convert 1D lat lon arrays using meshgrid but that won't work in this case because these are specific coordinates themselves. I tried to sort them in ascending lon and/or lat and/or both. Then I tried shifting the coordinates, reshaping them into factors of their total lengths but in vain.

**Data:**

```
    Longitude = [-10, -40, 34,  12, 67, ...]  # 138627 elements
    Latitude  = [ 23, -89, 67, -25, 92, ...]  # same
    Variable  = [  1,   2,  3,   4,  5, ...]  # same
```

**Code:**

```
    import cartopy, glob, warnings, os, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np, cartopy.crs as ccrs
    from   netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
    from   cartopy import config
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

    # CARTOPY
    ax      = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    plt.pcolormesh(Longitude, Latitude, Variable)
    ax.coastlines()
    plt.show()

    # BASEMAP
    m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlat=-90, llcrnrlon=-180,  rcrnrlat=90, urcrnrlon=180)

    #TRY 1
    new_coor = sorted([(i,j) for i,j in zip(Longitude, Latitude)], key=lambda x: x[0])
    shape     = (3,46209)  #len(Latitude) = 138627
    Longitude = np.asarray([i[0] for i in new_coor]).reshape(shape)
    Latitude  = np.asarray([i[1] for i in new_coor]).reshape(shape)
    xi, yi    = m(Longitude, Latitude)
    cs        = m.pcolor(xi, yi, np.squeeze(Variable)) #tried *pcolormesh* also
    # tried *m.shifting()* and *lat_lon = True* also
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries()

    cbar      = m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to get your data into a 2-D grid somehow to use `pcolormesh`, or triangulate it using `tripcolor`.  To grid the data have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html or links therein.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with unstructured data. You may want to define a [grid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) and to [interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) the data onto this grid, but in my opinion, a neater way is to use [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html). This function makes use of [triangulation](https://matplotlib.org/api/tri_api.html) so that your original data is not modified before being plotted. Useful keywords are, for example, antialiased, levels, extend, cmap.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
triMesh = Triangulation(Longitude, Latitude)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, num=0,
                       subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                       figsize=(16, 8))
ctrf = ax.tricontourf(triMesh, Variable)
cbar = fig.colorbar(ctrf)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I am still getting those weird areas filled with lines. @Patol75

Comment: It would help if you actually showed the figure which is plotted.